# Entered data in Html form is not forwarded to modal using @Modelattribute using Ajax request

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, spring-mvc

I am trying to make a form where user can add a product with its image. I am using Spring MVC. The issue is when I entered the data in the HTML form which is generated using Javascript and try to send the data using Ajax the data is not received by the controller in productDTO variable. I am getting it null. I am using `@ModalAttribute` annotation for that but it is not working. What am doing wrong?

Controller

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(path="/saveProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public APIResponseModel saveProduct(@ModelAttribute ProductDTO productDto, HttpSession session) {
        APIResponseModel apiResponseModel = new Utils().getDefaultApiResponse();
        UserModel user =  (UserModel) session.getAttribute("loggedInUser");
        BindingResult errorList = new DataBinder(new Object()).getBindingResult();
        logger.info("------------------------------------Logged In user info----------------------------------------------------");
        logger.info(user);
        logger.info("--"+productDto);
        logger.info("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        if(productDto != null && productDto.getBrand() != null) {
            productServ = new ProductServiceImpl();
            productServ.SaveProduct(productDto, user, null, errorList);
            if(!errorList.hasErrors()) {
                apiResponseModel.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK);
                apiResponseModel.setData(productDto.toString());
                apiResponseModel.setMessage("Product Saved Successfully !!");
            }else {
                errorList.addError(new ObjectError("error", "Please fill the mandatory fields"));
                apiResponseModel.setMessage("Please fill the mandatory fields");
            }
        }else {
            errorList.addError(new ObjectError("error", "Please fill the mandatory fields"));
            apiResponseModel.setMessage("Please fill the mandatory fields");
        }
        logger.info(apiResponseModel);
        return apiResponseModel;
    }
```

Product DTO used in controller

```
package com.Indoera.DTO;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.Indoera.Modal.UserModel;

public class ProductDTO {

    private Integer id;
    private Integer type;
    private Integer gender;
    private Integer quantity;
    private String brand;
    private Double price;
    private String description;
    private Integer market;
    private MultipartFile mainPic;
    private List<MultipartFile> additionalImages;
    
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Integer getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(Integer type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public Integer getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(Integer gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public Integer getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public MultipartFile getMainPic() {
        return mainPic;
    }
    public void setMainPic(MultipartFile mainPic) {
        this.mainPic = mainPic;
    }
    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }
    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }
    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public Integer getMarket() {
        return market;
    }
    public void setMarket(Integer market) {
        this.market = market;
    }
    public List<MultipartFile> getAdditionalImages() {
        return additionalImages;
    }
    public void setAdditionalImages(List<MultipartFile> additionalImages) {
        this.additionalImages = additionalImages;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{\"id\":\"" + id + "\", \"type\":\"" + type + "\", \"gender\":\"" + gender + "\", \"quantity\":\""
                + quantity + "\", \"brand\":\"" + brand + "\", \"price\":\"" + price + "\", \"description\":\""
                + description + "\", \"market\":\"" + market + "\", \"mainPic\":\"" + mainPic
                + "\", \"additionalImages\":\"" + additionalImages + "\"}";
    }
}
```

Code for generating the form and sending data to controller

```
function addProductForm(){
    htmlForm ="";
    htmlForm += "<div class=\"main-div\">"
    +"<form>"
    +"<input class=\"form-control\" id=\"brand\" type=\"text\"  placeholder=\"Brand name\">"
        +"<div class=\"form-group col-md-4\">"
                        +"<label for=\"inputGender\">Gender</label> <select id=\"gender\" class=\"form-control\" required>"
                        +"<option selected value=\"0\">Male</option>"
                        +"<option value=\"1\">Female</option>"
                        +"<option value=\"2\">Others</option>"
                        +"</select>"
                    +"</div>"
    +"<input class=\"form-control\" id=\"price\" type=\"number\"  placeholder=\"Price\">"
    +"<input class=\"form-control\" id=\"quantity\" type=\"number\"  placeholder=\"Quantity\">"

        +"<div class=\"form-group col-md-4\">"
                        +"<label for=\"input\">Cloth Type</label> <select id=\"type\" class=\"form-control\" required>"
                        +"<option selected value=\"0\">JEANS</option>"
                        +"<option value=\"1\">TOP</option>"
                        +"<option value=\"2\">SHOES</option>"
                        +"<option value=\"3\">SHIRTS</option>"
                        +"<option value=\"4\">SLIPPERS</option>"
                        +"<option value=\"5\">JACKETS</option>"
                        +"<option value=\"6\">SWEATER</option>"
                        +"<option value=\"7\">SWEATSHIRTS</option>"
                        +"</select>"
                    +"</div>"
        
        +"<div class=\"form-group\">"
            +"<label for=\"description\">Decsription</label>"
            +"<textarea class=\"form-control\" id=\"description\" rows=\"3\"></textarea>"
         + "</div>"
    
            +"<div class=\"form-group\">"
           +"<label for=\"mainPic\">Display Picture</label>"
           +" <input type=\"file\" class=\"form-control-file\" id=\"mainPic\">"
          +"</div>"
    
            +"<div class=\"form-group col-md-4\">"
                        +"<label for=\"market\">Market</label> <select id=\"market\" class=\"form-control\" required>"
                        +"<option selected value=\"0\">SAROJANI NAGAR</option>"
                        +"<option value=\"1\">PALIKA</option>"
                        +"<option value=\"2\">RAJPATH</option>"
                        +"</select>"
                    +"</div>"

    +"<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" onclick=\"saveProductInfo()\">Save Product</button>"
    +"</form>"
    +"</div>";
    
    document.getElementById("storeOwnerContent").innerHTML = htmlForm;
}

function saveProductInfo(){
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("brand", $("#brand").val());
    formData.append("type", $("#type").val());
    formData.append("gender", $("#gender").val());
    formData.append("quantity", $("#quantity").val());
    formData.append("price", $("#price").val());
    formData.append("description", $("#description").val());    
    formData.append("market", $("#market").val());  
    formData.append("mainPic", $("#mainPic").val());    

    var obj = new MasterAjax();
    obj.requestType = "POST";
    obj.url = "saveProduct";
    obj.data = formData;
    console.log("---------------------------")
    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
    }
    console.log("---------------------------")
    obj.enctype ="multipart/form-data";   
//  obj.contentType =false;
    obj.requestData(function(responseData){
        console.log(responseData);
        console.log("Response Data ----------------- : "+responseData.status);
        if(responseData.status == "OK"||responseData.status == "ok"){
            alert("success");
        }else{
            alert("Save failed");
        }
    }); 

}
```

Master Ajax class used in Ajax request

```
class MasterAjax{
    constructor(){
        this.requestType = null;
        this.url = null;
        this.timeout = 100000;
        this.enctype =  null;
        this.data = null;
        this.processData = null;
        this.contentType = null;
        this.responseData = null;
        this.responseStatus = null;
        this.responseStatusCode = null;
    }
    
    requestData(callBack){
        
        var parameterError=false;
        if(null == this.requestType){
            parameterError=true;
            console.log("Error: Request Type can't be null");
        }    
        if(null === this.url || undefined === this.url || "undefined" === this.url){
            parameterError=true;
            console.log("Error: URL can't be null");
        }  
        if(null == this.data || this.data.length <= 0){
            console.log("Warning: Data is null");
        }
        if(parameterError === false){
            /*toggleSpinnerOn();  */
            $.ajax({
                type : this.requestType,
                enctype : this.enctype,
                processData : this.processData, 
                contentType : this.contentType, 
                url : global_contextPath+"/"+this.url,
                data: this.data,
                timeout : this.timeout,
                success : function(responseData,textStatus) {
                    /*toggleSpinnerOff();*/
                    callBack(responseData,textStatus);
                },
                error : function(responseData,textStatus) {
                    /*toggleSpinnerOff();  */
                    callBack(responseData,textStatus); 
                }
            }); 
        }
return this.responseData;
    }
    
}
```

JSP page for the form

```
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/Header.jsp"%>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/ToIncludeConstants.jsp"%>


<div class="containers storeOwner" id="demo">

    <div id="StoreSidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="addProductForm()">Add Product</a>
        <a href="#">Products</a>
        <a href="#">Reports</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
      
      <!-- Use any element to open the sidenav -->
      <span onclick="openNav()"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
      
      <!-- Add all page content inside this div if you want the side nav to push page content to the right (not used if you only want the sidenav to sit on top of the page -->
      <div id="storeOwnerContent">
      </div>


</div>
```